# Code works as a Windows App but not as Web App (Datagrid vs GridView)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is the code for Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (AddressBookEntities dbcontext = new AddressBookEntities())
    {
        dbcontext.Addresses.OrderBy(name => name.FirstName);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        string lname = TextBox1.Text;

        lname = ToUpperFirstLetter(lname);



        GridView1.DataSource =
            dbcontext.Addresses.Local
                .Where(name => name.LastName == lname)
                .OrderBy(name => name.FirstName);

        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        GridView1.Enabled = true;


        //GridView1.Sort("FirstName",SortDirection.Ascending);

    }
```

Basically I'm trying to make the gridview display only the rows whose last name was typed in the text box.
This worked as a windows app but I am new to web app with c#. I'm having a hard time understanding why there is such a difference. The gridview is connected to a .mdf file.
Let me know if I need to add anything to help solve this.

Comment: What is the issue/question?

Comment: @zespri my problem is that I want to filter a gridview to show only the rows that has the last name that the user typed into a box. That is the code for when the user has clicked the submit button.

Comment: The difference is that anything you do in a Web app means post back and page lifecycle. You can't expect everything just work on-fly like in the windows app

Comment: @T.S. Then how would I do that but as a web app?

Comment: If you want really responsive web app client, you need to load data into JavaScript array and use some JavasScript to search your array. When I say JavaScript, I mean any js library. You can do less-responsive stuff, such as type the last name, click the button - page will go back to server, code will run and select records you need and then it will be rendered to the client. But this is a postback in Asp.net world. In windows app, you may just keep on searching same Datasource. Thre is big difference

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below, set the data source ( Note: I have added `.ToList()`) and you need to call `DataBind` method

```
GridView1.DataSource =
    dbcontext.Addresses.Local
        .Where(name => name.LastName == lname)
        .OrderBy(name => name.FirstName).ToList();

GridView1.DataBind();
```